# php Preg_match_all get all links with specified characters

Tags: php, preg-match

I wanna extract all links from a page that have this pattern:

`http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/e/(numeric ID)/(team1)+v+(team2).html`

any idea what the `preg_match_all()` expression should be?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If team1 and team2 have only letters. Preg match should be like this.

```
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/sports\.williamhill\.com\/bet\/en-gb\/betting\/e\/\d+\/\w+\+v\+\w+\.html/', $input, $matches);
```

Comment: thanks , mate can i ask you another question? what if in some links the team has 2 names like : ' \betting\(num id)\Crystal+Palace+v+Huddresfield.html' ?

Comment: Then you should change this part "\w+\+v\+\w+" to "[\w+]+\+v\+[\w+]+"

Comment: thanks again m8 i was trying to do it by writing 4 lines of pregmatch and checking with if's if i got any value... you saved me from a lot of trouble